# How do I stop audio clicking/popping over SPDIF?

Tags: 16.04, sound, spdif

Here's a [recording](https://clyp.it/tjikxjz3) of what my audio output sounds like. I am using a USB sound card identified as C-Media Electronics, Inc. CM106 Like Sound Device which is outputed over optical SPDIF to a Denon 5.1 receiver. In Windows, I have no issues with the audio. Under Ubuntu 16.04 there's a constant clicking/popping which is louder as the sound is louder.

I visited other posts and followed a few suggestions like installing pulse audio, changing mixer settings, and other attempts but it still continues. It doesn't happen over HDMI or analog.

Comment: Have you checked the [audio troubleshooting docs](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SoundTroubleshootingProcedure)

Comment: Same issue, also c-media via SPDIF to a Sony 7.1.

Answer (score 5):

Had same problem on megeia 6, found it to be a sample-rate problem. Adding default-sample-rate = 48000 to /etc/pulse/daemon.conf fixed it for me.
pulse needs to restart after. pulseaudio -k, pulseaudio --start

Comment: How did you decide to use 48000?

Comment: It was suggestion on https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/PulseAudio/Troubleshooting under Choppy/distorted sound.

Comment: Thanks for this tip! I was using Ubuntu 20.04 and routing the audio to one of the Steelseries GameDAC devices (using the PS4 input). This worked like a treat.